# How to use Python startswith method for combination of unicode and ascii string?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, python-unicode

In my case, I have Unicode text_string and prefix as ASCII string, when I use

```
text-string.startswith(prefix)
```

I am getting an exception in this way

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)`

how to compare both strings, I tried converting ASCII string to Unicode using **unicode(string)** method but still got the same exception.

how to solve this? In worst case how to suppress this exception while comparison?

```
text - u'PreciChrom I/II is a lyophilized control based on human citrated plasma.'
prefix - 'Reagents – working solutions'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], your question is off-topic without one.

Comment: Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: 2.7, hope my team migrates someday to 3.x

Comment: That's still a bit from code I can just run. That said, your ASCII string simply isn't ASCII, it contains a byte with the value 0xe2 at position 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your prefix string is *not* ASCII. As the error message says, you have a non-ASCII character in position 9; the en dash, `–`. The string is probably utf-8.

You can just decode the prefix to unicode:

```
text_string.startswith(prefix.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`text_string.encode().startswith(prefix)`